# Batch wont let me use > and <

Tags: batch-file

I need some help to fix my bat file.

```
@echo off
set Output="%USERPROFILE%\desktop"

set /p derpz=Enter variable one value: 
set /p VarTwo=Enter variable two value: 
set /p VarThree=Enter variable three value: 
set /p VarFour=Enter variable four value: 

REM enter your desired output here
echo <derp>%derpz%</derp> >> %Output%\test.txt
echo <derp>%vartwo%</derp> >> %Output%\test.txt
echo <derp>%VarThree%"</derp> >> %Output%\test.txt
echo <derp>%VarFour%</derp> >> %Output%\test.txt

echo.
echo File has been placed %Output%
pause
```

that should create a new txt with the text and where %varXXX% it should let me put my own custom message.

I think i have figured out why it dont't work, it's because i use < and > in the text, is there any way for the bat to allow me to do that?

Comment: feel like putting a "status:by-design" on this.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
echo ^<derp^>%derpz%^</derp^> >> %Output%\test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET derp=^^^<derp^^^>
SET pred=^^^<\derp^^^>

ECHO %derp%derpz%pred% >xderp.txt

TYPE xderp.txt
```

Personally, I'd do something like this to save all the carets...